# problema de criar projeto android no netbeans

Tags: android

não consigo criar um projeto android netbeans por que aparece isso na minha tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando eu seleciono uma plataforma de android ele dar mensagem de bug

porque será que isso estar acontecendo..

estar tudo instalado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**ESSA É A MENSAGEM DE ERRO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação:

> To avoid conflicts with other developers, you should use Internet domain ownership as the basis for your package names (in reverse). For example, applications published by Google start with com.google. You should also never use the com.example namespace when publishing your applications.
>   The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application. It's also the default name for the application process (see the  element's process process attribute) and the default task affinity of an activity (see the  element's taskAffinity attribute).

O package name serve como identificador único para aplicação e para evitar conflitos você deve usar o domínio da internet do dono da aplicação invertido, por exemplo, aplicações da Google começam com `com.google`. Para nível de testes você pode usar o package name `com.testes` que seria o contrario de um suposto `http://testes.com`.

Provavelmente existe alguma verificação que se baseia no fato de que nenhum dominio possui apenas uma parte, logo a IDE faz o teste se seu pacote tem ao menos duas parte, caso não tenha ele não permite que você avance.

Referência: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package)

Comment: Apenas para completar: o correto é usar o seu domínio principal + o 'subdominio' (pode não existir de verdade) para identificar melhor seu aplicativo, porque seu eu fizer dois aplicativos com o nome com.google vai dar conflito, para isso deve ser usado com.google.meuprojeto

Comment: @OlimonF. é vdd, faltou eu falar do subdominio. Eu acabei me apegando ao texto da documentação e no caso ele omite os detalhes do que vem a seguir do `com.google`. Obrigado por ressaltar.